# Rails merge array into array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I have a weird array situation that I'm unable to figure out how to execute efficiently.

I have this starting array of arrays:

```
[["6884", true], ["8456", false], ["5631", false]]
```

Then I have another 1D array:

```
["6884", "8023", "9837"]
```

I want to merge the 1D array into the array of arrays by appending the value to the end of the array at the same index in the 2D array.

So the final product should be:

```
[["6884", true, "6884"], ["8456", false, "8023"], ["5631", false, "9837]]
```

So the value at index 0 in the 1D array is appended to the end of the array at index 0 in the 2D array, and so on for each element in the 1D array. Is there an easy Ruby way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `zip` and `flatten` methods like this:

```rb
a = [["6884", true], ["8456", false], ["5631", false]]
b = ["6884", "8023", "9837"]

a.zip(b)
# [[["6884", true], "6884"], [["8456", false], "8023"], [["5631", false], "9837"]]

# Then use flatten to this array:
a.zip(b).map(&:flatten)
# [["6884", true, "6884"], ["8456", false, "8023"], ["5631", false, "9837"]]
```

Comment: Only note is that this could be consumptive on a larger data set as it creates `N * N + 2` new Arrays where `N = a.size`

Answer (score 5):

Further to [Mehmet Adil İstikbal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73449378/1954610), here's another approach -- just to show that There's More Than One Way To Do It:

```
a = [["6884", true], ["8456", false], ["5631", false]]
b = ["6884", "8023", "9837"]

a.map.with_index { |item, index| item.push(b[index]) }
# => [["6884", true, "6884"], ["8456", false, "8023"], ["5631", false, "9837"]]
```

Comment: This also works well, I just prefer the cleanliness of Mehmet's answer. Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that this mutates `a`.

Answer (score 3):

```
a2 = [["6884", true], ["8456", false], ["5631", false]]
a1 = ["6884", "8023", "9837"]
```

```
a2.zip(a1).map { |e2, e1| [*e2, e1] }
```

or, to avoid the creation of the temporary array `a2.zip(a1)`,

```
a1.each_index.map { |i| [*a2[i], a1[i]] }
```

Both return

```
[["6884", true, "6884"], ["8456", false, "8023"], ["5631", false, "9837"]]
```

Note that neither expression mutates `a2` or `a1`. See [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) (which, without a block, returns an enumerator) and [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: I understood where you were going. Iterative methods, especially ones that take a block, can be confusing in ruby because some return immediately and others return Enumerators. `zip`'s block is extra confusing since it yields the zipped elements but always returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the first array you can pass a block to `zip` to append the latter elements to the corresponding sub-array:

```
a = [["6884", true], ["8456", false], ["5631", false]]
b = ["6884", "8023", "9837"]

a.zip(b) { |ary, el| ary << el }

a
# => [["6884", true, "6884"], ["8456", false, "8023"], ["5631", false, "9837"]]
```